# is using "to not" acceptible in this context?

Tags: grammar

I was asked to combine sentences in my English and I wrote:

The mouse moves at night to not risk daylight raid on the pantry.

is using (to not) acceptable as a way to combine the two sentences?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Can I ask what two sentences you were trying to combine?

Comment: I don't remember it verbatim but it was something like this: The mouse moves at night. He doesn't want to risk a daylight risk on the pantry.

Answer (score 1):

Using `to not` is a perfectly acceptable way to combine two ideas (given the context and the rest of the grammar is proper).

I don't fully understand the sentence you were writing, but a sentence such as

> The mouse moves at night to not draw attention from the house owners.

would be another example of using `to not` to combine two ideas

Answer (score -2):

You did split the infinitive.  The prevailing attitude is that it is acceptable to do so (but I generally avoid doing so when it isn't awkward to avoid).  You probably need the indefinite article "a" before daylight.  Regarding "to", it's not wrong.  Other ways of saying it would be:

```
The mouse moves at night so as not to risk a daylight raid on the pantry.
The mouse moves at night lest it risk a daylight raid on the pantry.
The mouse moves at night in order not to risk a daylight raid on the pantry.
```

Comment: If you know that the splitting an finitive rule is an aberration, why put it centre-stage inn your answer? Delete that rubbish, and I'll give you an upvote ....

Comment: It’s not clear why “to not” is under question initially.  Is it because the asker is concerned about splitting an infinitive or is it a question of whether the construction is awkward? We don’t know, so I addressed (1) that the prevailing opinion is that it is acceptable to split the infinitive, and I suggested (2) alternative expressions that sound more natural but have the same meaning.

Comment: Ok. -1 for avoiding it when it isn't awkward, because this comes across as advice for the reader, though. It's bad advice.

Comment: I would consider “so as to not” a mildly awkward construction.